# Javascript Regex match no spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match the following string in Javascript Regex

> PC123456

This is what I have:

```
/^PC\d*/
```

This works for every instance minus one with a space after the "PC" which does work but it should fail.
Example:

> PC 123456

That should fail. What do I need to add to make the second condition fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your regex to this:

```
/^PC\d+$/
```

This requires at least one digit and only matches if there is nothing else in the string except the `PC` and the digits.

This will match:

```
PC123456
PC1
PC99
```

It will not match:

```
PC 12345
PC
PCx1234
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an end-of-source anchor:

```
/^PC\d*$/
```

The "$" at the end insists that the pattern match the *entire* string. Without it, "PC" with no immediately subsequent digits matches because "*" means "zero or more", not "one or more".

You could alternatively change the "*" to a "+", but I don't know whether "PC" by itself is valid in your application.

Answer (score 2):

Require at least one digit after `PC`

```
/^PC\d+/
```

or require the String to last the entire line

```
/^PC\d*$/
```